# Include Z3 in a C++ project

Tags: llvm, z3

I want to use Z3 in a llvm project(file directory copied from its sample project). What I did now is just simply include z3++.h without adding any other code in the source file and want to pass the compilation. But I don't know how to deal with modifying makefile to make it work. I tried a few times it reports error like "exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable" and other linking errors. Can someone give me a hint on how to change the makefile to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me which makefile is being modified, I can only speak for Z3. The c++ example doesn't have its own makefile, but it has targets in z3/build/Makefile called cpp_example$(EXE_EXT) and _ex_cpp_example. The variables used by the commands in these targets are in z3/build/config.mk and if -fexceptions is needed, it can be added to the CXXFLAGS variable there.

Roughly, the example should need -I /path/to/z3++.h -I /path/to/z3.h -L /path/to/libz3.so and -lz3 and when running Z3 the path to libz3.so needs to be in PATH (Windows), LD_LIBRARY_PATH (Linux), or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH (OSX).

Comment: Thanks. I have Z3 installed in the usr/bin and hearder files installed in the system directory as well. The real issue for me is how to change llvm sample project makefile to make it work. Turns out it can be solved by adding LIBS += -lz3 AFTER the statement "include LEVEL/makefile.common" in makeifle belongs to the source file.

Comment: you get this error since llvm by default is compiled with -fno-exception(and -fno-rtti), while z3 uses exception; however it doesn't matter in ABI level. It seems that you find the way later.