# Z3 in LLVM project, "error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable"

Tags: exception, llvm, z3

Z3-4.3.2, ubuntu12.04.64

I have a LLVM project works well without Z3, which compiled configured with “–fno-exceptions”.But now I want to add solver module with Z3 to my project, there is “error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable”. This problem is same as

[Include Z3 in a C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025779/include-z3-in-a-c-project)

Before that, Z3 is compiled successfully with default configuration. In order to make LLVM project compiled, I recompiled Z3 with “–fno-exceptions”(in build/config.mk), however, there is same error as compiled LLVM project when recompiled Z3.

Any tips for solving this problem, or Z3 cannot be compiled with “-fno-exceptions”

Answer (score 1):

Z3 uses exceptions, so you cannot compile it with -fno-exceptions.

Comment: that means any project compiled with "-fno-exceptions" cannot work with Z3?